# auto grant permission on android marshmallow in android

Tags: android, android-permissions

I want to give auto grant permissions external storage permissions without promoting request permission dialog box on android marshmallow devices. Is there any any way to access system permission xml file .I have tired using adb but it is not working on non rooted devices .Please help .

Thanks

Comment: You can't do that without requesting the user. This is for the security purpose.

Comment: There is an easier way for that ,just change your `targetSdkVersion` to 22

Comment: @sunilsunny still it wont work on M and heigher

Comment: @EbyCloudins May I know why ?. RunTimePermissions was introduced in api 23. So if your app is targeting older api's the permission will get auto approved like in earlier version. Only one downside : From api 23 onward the users can navigate into apps->permissions and switch on and off permissions which they feel unsafe. In that case apps that not following the new RunTimePermissions won't work.

Comment: so in M and higher user have to give permission manually right?

Answer (score 1):

keep compileSdk and targetSdk as 21 or less than 23.(Just work around)

**Note: This is just an Work Around**

After applying this, you will not able to upload app on Playstore as [described 
here](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2017/12/improving-app-security-and-performance.html)